# Hibernate annotation inheritance OneToMany Placemant

Tags: java, inheritance, hibernate-annotations

Need help implement this scenario in Hibernate inheritance

Cow and Dog are inheriting Animal class,

Both Cow and Dog have "offspring" list

 Cow have additional list - monthly vaccine dates 

Will this Hibernate representation will be correct?

Is it correct to put the OneToMany Vaccine list on the Cow class 

 or Its need to be on the Animal class??

Thank you!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "animals")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="animal_type")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Animal{

 @Id
 @Column(name = "animalId" ,nullable = false)
 private String animalId;

 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Animal> offsprings = new ArrayList<Animal>();

public List<Animal> getOffsprings() {
    return offsprings;
}

...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("COW")
public class Coe extends Animal {

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 **private List<Vaccine> vaccine = new ArrayList<Vaccine>();**

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DOG")
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private chipId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in the cow class, as in your case it is a property specific for cows, not dogs.

Both entities however, are stored in a single table. This means that within the DB, there is nothing to prevent dogs from having vaccines as well.

If you have more properties like vaccines, that belong to a cow rather than to a dog, I would reconsider my inheritance strategy.

Comment: Thanks, if Donkey class need to have Vaccines also, is it correct to put intermediate abstract class between Animal and [Donkey, Cow] to hold the Vaccine list?

Comment: That's perfectly ok. I'd also choose to make the intermediate class abstract, as it's not an animal and thus will never have to be instantiated on its own.